# List of reserved parameter names for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

It seems that the GET parameter `location` is a reserved parameter on AWS S3. Say I have a resource on an S3 bucket, accessible via the web:

http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

... and I simply append the GET parameter `location` to it, I get an HTTP 403:

http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?location=US

It works so long as I change the parameter name to something else. For example:

http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?loc=US

So clearly `location` is a reserved word in AWS S3. My question is: **is there a list of all reserved words I shouldn't try to use as GET parameters with S3?**

I searched the docs but couldn't find any such list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location` in the query tells S3 that you're asking for the location of a bucket.  It's one of several "subresources" (things that are not objects) in S3 that are accessed via query string parameters.

You could probably compile a nearly complete list by reviewing the entire API reference documentation, but here's a partial list found in some older docs (Signature Version 2):

> The subresources that must be included when constructing the CanonicalizedResource Element are acl, lifecycle, location, logging, notification, partNumber, policy, requestPayment, torrent, uploadId, uploads, versionId, versioning, versions, and website.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

They periodically add new ones, like `select` and `delete` and `tagging`, so an exhaustive list is not future-proof.

Your safest bet is to use parameters beginning with `x-` (but not beginning with `x-amz` since these may be reserved or carry other implications).  This is mentioned in the logging documentation:

> You can include custom information to be stored in the access log record for a request by adding a custom query-string parameter to the URL for the request. Amazon S3 ignores query-string parameters that begin with "x-", but includes those parameters in the access log record for the request, as part of the Request-URI field of the log record.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html